# Remove \n but keep \r\n intact

Tags: c#

I got a string with many line breaks. There are two types of them.
\n and \r\n i want to keep the \r\n line breaks but i want to get rid of the \n ones. Is there any easy way of doing this? Am afraid if i use the replace method it would also affect my \r\n breaks.

```
string text = "This is a \ntext there should \nonly be one line break\r\n";

var newtext = text.Replace("\n", "");
```

Here the output would be

```
newtext = "This is a text there should only be one line break\r"
```

How do i make this string to output "This is a text there should only be one line break\r\n" ?

Comment: Using a regular expression you should be able to target the \n and not \r\n

Answer (score 3):

You can use Regex

```
var text2 = Regex.Replace(text, @"([^\r])\n", "$1");
```

Comment: it's also taking away one space with \n

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regular Expression with a look-behind that will only replace `\n` characters that are not preceded by `\r` :

```
var replacement = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<!\r)\n","");
```

You can [see a working example in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wAeQPL) that uses the following input :

```
Regex.Replace("Line 1\n Still Line 1\r\nLine 2\n Still Line 2", @"(?<!\r)\n","");
```

which yields :

```
Line 1 Still Line 1
Line 2 Still Line 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var replacedText = Regex.Replace(text, "(?<!\\r)\\n","");
```

[image]